# How to retrieve value from a row with changed textfield with Eureka form?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I'm trying to retrieve the value of the typed field in a row of an Eureka form (https://eurekacommunity.github.io). I've set up a new textfield with a mask, but when I send it back it returns me empty.

TextRow:

```
<<< TextRow(Constants.CPF) {
        $0.title = Constants.cpf_title
        $0.placeholder = Constants.cpf_placeholder
    }
    .cellSetup { cell, _ in
        let tf = JMMaskTextField(frame: cell.textField.frame)
        tf.maskString = "000.000.000-00"
        cell.textField.removeFromSuperview()
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell.textField = tf
        cell.contentView.addSubview(tf)
    }
    .cellUpdate { cell, _ in
        cell.textField.delegate = self
    }
```

Result:

```
let values = self.form.values()
print(values[Constants.CPF])
```

> Optional(nil)

Apparently the mask is working properly, but I think I'm forgetting to set something up. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Take a look on [Callbacks list](https://github.com/xmartlabs/eureka#callbacks-list) section.

Comment: As you removed the `textField` that had setup for updating the value so now you have to set the value for row when your textField (JMMaskTextField) is changing the text. May be in `textFieldDidEndEditing` you need to set the value for `TextRow` if you want that value inside `self.form.values()`.

Comment: As you are setting your `ViewController` as `textField delegate` so i really don't think you need to use the `form.values()` dictionary because you are already getting that value from the `textField delegate`.

Comment: this idea did not work very well @Kamran . It is now returning an empty string. And if the user clicks on completing the form without clicking or another text field the value is not updated in the same way. I use delegate in this field because I need to change the mask type at typing time because of the phones here in Brazil, which can be "(00) 0 0000-0000" or "(00) 0000-0000".

Comment: @ThomasMarques " It is now returning an empty string" what is returning nil? If user does not click what value is not updating? Can you share more code related to textField delegate and form values requirement after user input.

Comment: Can you share enough code to produce your issue and provide you a fix?

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Kamran , but I was able to recover the values like this: `let cpf = (self.form.rowBy(tag: Constants.CPF)?.baseCell.baseRow as! TextRow).cell.textField.text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use different `UITextField` in your row, you should [create custom row](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#custom-rows) for that. In this case, you can subclass from `TextRow` and implement you cell with `JMMaskTextField`. Just remove default `textField` and set the new (as you did) doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll implement.